# What is this game? It's pixelated, and looks like a roguelike

Tags: game-identification

Please note the clip of the game I'm talking about is in timestamp 0:16. The game which I want to identify is not Yandere Simulator.[image: Screenshot.]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The game is [Nuclear Throne](https://store.steampowered.com/app/242680/Nuclear_Throne/), and it is indeed a top-down roguelite shooter.

Comment: Do you mean "roguelike", or is "roguelite" a new genre I haven't heard of before?

Comment: @nick012000 [What's the difference between a “Roguelike” and a “Roguelite” game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246887/)